# Applying linear regression to a data subset

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, subset

I've just run a linear regression on an entire data set, but now I need to run the regression with data just from females within the data.

Females are denoted under the `female` column of the data set by a `1`. Males are denoted by a `0` under the same column. I don't know how to remove the male data so I can run the regression on female data only.

Comment: This looks like routine bookwork. Is this for some subject? If you do need (for some non-obvious reason) to actually run a regression on a subset (see Andre's comment for why in general it's not necessary), the following approach is pretty typical. If `mydata` is a data frame containing `y,x1,x2` and `sex`, then instead of `lm(y~x1+x2,data=mydata)` you replace the `data=` argument with one that appropriately subsets the rows of `mydata` by the relevant value of `sex`.

Comment: I don't really need to remove the male data, I just need to run the regression on only females.  I have a "female" column in which females are denoted 1, and males are denoted 0.  My current code looks like this:  lm(y~x,data=mydata)  I just don't know what to add to that to make it only run for rows that have female  =1

Comment: I thought I'd just go ahead and answer, because this is quite easy. However, the others are right; simple code requests belong on Stack Overflow, and in this case, you could probably Google it very quickly (that's why I'm not flagging to migrate – it's a little *too* simple – though I don't mind if it gets migrated). In fact, [the first Google hit for "code for excluding conditions in r"](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html) contains my answer, and several alternatives (hence I've edited it in)!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use r.

Comment: Your question is then actually how do I *subset a data frame in R*? which can be very helpful if you google it. Using `mydata[as.logical(mydata$female),]` as your data set in `lm` is one of half a dozen obvious ways (`mydata[mydata$female==1,]` is another; as is using `subset`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lm(y~x,data=subset(mydata,female==1))`. `subset()` allows you to set a variety of conditions for retaining observations in the object nested within, such as `>`, `!=`, and `==`. The last of these excludes all observations for which the value is not exactly what follows. `!=` would do the opposite.

For a variety of other alternatives, see [Quick-R on subsetting data](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html). Some of these may better serve different or more advanced coding goals.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Also, the third argument to `lm` is for subsetting.